# how to store button and textfield value when come back from other view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have three view in my app. In first view there are three `button` and two `textfields`. When I press in any `button` there is a drop down list of `tableview` chosen item from `tableview` will be button title and in `textfield` the value will be from keyboard.

When I jump into second view to do my stuffs and come back to first view then the button title which I selected from `tableview` is not appear on `button` title as well as in `textfields`.

So,what to do to set `button` title and `textfield` value. I don't want to pass value from one view to second view.

Comment: you store value in nsuserdefault and set Button title in viewWillAppear method @bhavinramani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSUserdefaults` to store the value of  `button & textfield`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 // Store the data
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourTextfieldName.Text forKey:@"txtNmae"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cell.yourbuttonName.titleLabel.text forKey:@"buttonName"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

}
```

get the data from NSuserdefaults as

```
// Get the stored data before the view loads

 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];



 NSString * txtName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"txtNmae"];
if(txtName)
{
 yourtextField.text= txtName;
 }
else
 {
  yourtextField.text= @"";
 }

  NSString * buttonName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"buttonName"];
 if(buttonName)
 {
[yourbuttonName setTitle: buttonName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
else
 {
  [yourbuttonName setTitle: @"as your Wish" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }


 // remove the userDefaultValue

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"buttonName"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"txtNmae"];

 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the strings in NSUserDefaults. When didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called, save the button title in like this

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObjectForKey:cell.titleLabel.text forKey:@"button_title"];
```

Do the same for `textField`.
Set the title of button like this
And for the first time to check if the NSUserDefaults contains data, apply this

```
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"button_title"]){
        [self.button setTitle:@"anyString" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        //set button from user defaults.
NSString *buttonTitle=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"button_title"];
[self.button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

and set the static button title by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSUserdefaults to store the button title & textfield values as

```
 NSString *firstName = [firstNameTextField text];
NSString *lastName  = [lastNameTextField text];

 // Store the data
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
[defaults setObject:lastName forKey:@"lastname"];
```

& get the data from NSuserdefaults as

```
// Get the stored data before the view loads
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *firstName = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstName"];
NSString *lastName = [defaults objectForKey:@"lastname"];


// Update the UI elements with the saved data
firstNameTextField.text = firstName;
lastNameTextField.text = lastName;
```

check 1st the NSUserdefaults value is not Null for 1st time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store title for temporary purpose then No need to use `NSUserDefaults`. NSUserDefault is used to store value permanent mean till user delete app. If you want title after user kill and reopen app then only use NSUserDefaults.

You can define NSString in AppDelegate and use it or you can define NSString in Global class.

in **AppDelegate**

```
@property(nonatomic,Strong)NSString *strTitle;
```

store this value using below code

```
AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appDel.strTitle = @"your title";
```

and it will store value till user kill your app.So use as per your need.